# struts2, jquery grid is not displaying results

Tags: jquery, struts2

The below grid is not displaying any results. The results are stored in a collection called eventList

```
<sjg:grid
    autowidth="true"
        id="gridloadtable"
        loadonce="true"
        caption="Search Results"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        gridModel="eventList"
        rowNum="-1"
        hidegrid="false"
        scroll="true"
        cellEdit="true"
        cellurl="%{editcellurl}"
    >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eventName" index="eventName" title="Company" sortable="true" href="/thankyou.jsp" targets="eventSearchResultsDiv"/>

    </sjg:grid>
    <sj:submit id="grid_load_colsbutton"
            value="Show/Hide Columns"
            onClickTopics="showloadcolumns"
            button="true"/>
```

I can access the results using an iterator in my jsp -

```
<s:iterator value="eventList" var="event">
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read the [grid docs in the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag).

for the grid you need a JSON Action which provides the data for the grid.

[image: Struts2 jQuery Grid - Architecture]

Johannes

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am receiving an error when I try to create the json table class -

Comment: @Actions( {
    @Action(value = "/jsontable", results = {
      @Result(name = "success", type = "json")
    })
  })
Do I need to define these annotations? Or should it work if I remove them?

Comment: this annotions are the action configuration via convention plugin

Comment: I'm receiving this error when trying to define @ParentPackage(value = "showcase")                                                      Multiple markers at this line
 - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type ParentPackage
 - ParentPackage cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Should these annotations be automatically picked up? thanks again

Comment: do you have the struts2-convention-plugin.jar in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define parentpackage as showcase.
Define your own package just like you do in normal struts2 and extend it to struts-default, json-default.